# How to keep a randomization formula from randomizing at each change in the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, random, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have this cute formula:

```
=sort(A1:A416,arrayFormula(randbetween(sign(row(A1:A416)),C1)),true)
```

I thought I could change the randomization event when I changed the value in `C1`, but now I see this is changing continuously when I update the sheet with other values.

How can I keep this from happening?

I only want the randomization to happen when I change the seed in `C1`.

Comment: Do you need to use this with a formula? Maybe you can use an onEdit() trigger in Apps Script?

Comment: your issue is solvable only with script or macro

Answer (score 0):

Try using this edit trigger in your script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C1') {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var firstRow = 1;
    var lastRow = 416;
    var col = 1;
    var seedValue = Number(e.range.getValue());
    if(seedValue > 1) {
      for(var row = firstRow; row < lastRow; row++) {
        var cellValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * seedValue);
        var cell = sheet.getRange(row, col);
        cell.setValue(cellValue);
      }
    }
    var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, col, lastRow, 1)
    range.sort(1);
  }  
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve with your formula.